# After upgrading to .net 6. I receive errors when posting multipart formdata. The request is proxied using Yarp

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, ms-yarp

After upgrading to .net 6, I receive errors when posting multipart formdata through a proxy. The request is proxied using Yarp.

The other requests and posts work. I have tried to use HTTP 1.1 but it still gives the same task cancelled error. I have also tried with a different proxy. (ProxyKit).

```
Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[9]
      Proxying to http://THECORRECTADDRESS HTTP/2 RequestVersionOrLower no-streaming
Forwarder Telemetry [IPNUMBER] => OnForwarderStage :: Stage: SendAsyncStart
info: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[48]
      RequestCanceled: The request was canceled before receiving a response.
      System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Forwarder Telemetry [IPNUMBER] => OnForwarderFailed :: Error: RequestCanceled
Forwarder Telemetry [IPNUMBER] => OnForwarderStop :: Status: 502
```

The server does not log anything.

Are there any ideas on how I should troubleshoot this?

Comment: When you say "upgrading to .NET 6", can you clarify what exactly was updated and from what version? For example, was the proxy also updated, or is it just the client sending the message that was updated? If it was only the client, can you compare how the request payload looks like before and after the update? You should be able to temporarily enable HTTP request logging on the client API to capture the payloads. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.